# Using correct_user before filter in controller giving me an error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am fairly new and have searched and couldn't find this issue. Hoping someone can help me.

I have a session helper called correct_user as per the Ruby on Rails Tutorial. I originally had it in my users_controller but moved it to the session helper as I want to use the before filter in not only my users_controller but also my timesheets_controller (which I use when a user enters their daily time)

Here is my session helper:

```
def correct_user
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    unless current_user?(@user)
        redirect_to(root_url)
    end  
 end
```

Here is relevant part of my timesheets_controller.rb:

```
before_filter :correct_user, only: [:show, :create]

def new
end

def show
    @timesheet = Timesheet.new
    @timesheets = Timesheet.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 10)
end

def index
    @timesheets = Timesheet.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 10)
end

def create
    @timesheet = current_user.timesheets.create(params[:timesheet])
    if @timesheet.save
       @timesheet.approved = false
       @timesheet.save
       flash[:success] = "Timesheet Entered!"
       redirect_to current_user
    else
      render 'show'
    end
end
```

For some reason the show works perfectly fine, however the create is causing an error to be thrown:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in TimesheetsController#create

Couldn't find User without an ID
Rails.root: /Users/vinaymal/Documents/Vinay/Coding/rails_projects/SSSERP

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb:46:in `correct_user'
```

Line 46 is:

```
@user = User.find(params[:id])
```

How do I modify this so that it picks up the correct user. Any why isn't it causing an issue for the show action ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When used in the context of a `User` operation, `params[:id]` is the `id` of the user. However, in the context of a `Timesheet` operation, `params[:id]` is the `id` of the timesheet, or `nil` in the case of the create operation.

In the case of the timesheet, what you want to be checking for all operations *other* than `create` is that the `current_user` is the same as the user who created the timesheet.

Comment: No. The `show` check is only succeeding in your test example because the timesheet `id` is coincidentally the same as the user `id` and `create` check is failing. You need to change your code to compare the currently logged in user (see the Sessions reference in the other answer) to the user associated with the timesheet and not do that comparison for the `create` case.

Comment: Ok I just so happen to have that as per the Rails Tutorial as well. It looks like this: before_filter :signed_in_user, only: [:show, :index, :destroy, :approve, :unapprove] I thought I had to have both just like I needed both for the users_controller. Should I just eliminate the correct_user before_filter if its not really checking anything as per Adrian CB above ?

Comment: It depends on what you want. If any signed in user is allowed to operate on any time sheet, then you don't need anything beyond `signed_in_user` (i.e. authentication). However, if you want to limit certain timesheet operations to the owner of the timesheet, then you'll need a functioning `correct_user` (i.e. authorization).

Comment: To be clear, `correct_user` would be different for `User` and `Timesheet`. There's precedence for this in the tutorial, as you'll see if you search for `def correct_user` (e.g. Listing 10.46 in current version).

Comment: You are right !!! I must be slow. So I will keep a diffent correct_user in both the controllers. Many thanks for this I really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I believe `@user = User.find(params[:id])` doesn't work correctly for either action; it's a false positive.

It just so happens that you have a User with the same id as the Timesheet you're viewing, probably `1`.

I would change your helper to:

```
User.find(session[:user_id])
```

and on login store the user id in the session hash as `user_id` eg:

```
session[:user_id] = @current_user.id
```

If you need a better understanding of Sessions, check out the guide [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#what-are-sessions-questionmark).

Comment: but then this would break my correct_user filter for my users_controller wouldn't it ? The helper was copied directly from The Ruby on Rails Tutorial.